# How to pivot a table with 4 columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data frame with 4 columns and I want to pivot it the following way:

ORIGINAL TABLE:

| RA | T | V | ES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | ee | 0 | AA |
| 01 | dd | -1 | AA |
| 01 | hh | 9 | AA |
| 02 | ee | 0 | AA |
| 02 | dd | 8 | AA |
| 02 | hh | -2 | AA |
| 03 | ee | 5 | BB |
| 03 | dd | 3 | BB |
| 03 | hh | 4 | BB |
| 04 | ee | -7 | CC |
| 04 | dd | 2 | CC |
| 04 | hh | 0 | CC |

DESIRED TABLE AFTER PIVOTING:

| RA | ee | dd | hh | ES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 0 | -1 | 9 | AA |
| 02 | 0 | 8 | -2 | AA |
| 03 | 5 | 3 | 4 | BB |
| 04 | -7 | 2 | 0 | CC |

In the past I pivot a table with 3 columns and it worked just fine. This time, I want

**RA** to be the **index**

**T** to be the **columns**

**V** to be the **values**

**ES** to keep as is (as described above).

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `index=['RA','ES']`

Comment: @jezraels input plus after pivoting use `.reset_index(level='ES')`

Comment: @jezrael Will it work even though 'ES' is not unique in the pivoted table?

Comment: @Rabinzel - When I try "RA" as index it works but "ES" doesn't appear in the pivoted table. However, when I try "ES" as index or ["RA", "ES"] as index it fails..

Comment: @Eli based on your provided example I used this line and got your desired output: `df.pivot(index=['RA', 'ES'], columns='T', values='V').reset_index(level='ES')`. Did you try it like this and it failed? What error message did you get?